# Showing submenuItem from "New"Menu in Both PackageExplorer and ProjectExplorer

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

In Eclipse plugin.xml,how to make a submenuItem from New Menu to be visible not only in project explorer but also in package explorer.

My source code is ...

```xml
  <extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
     <menuContribution
        allPopups="true"
        locationURI="popup:common.new.menu?after=additions">
          <command
           commandId="org.eclipse.ui.newWizard"
           icon="icons/schema-file_16x16.png"
           label="%schemaFile.command.label"
           style="push">             
         </command>    
      </menu>
  </extension>
```

But this submenu is only visible in ProjectExplorer, but not in PackageExplorer.
How to do to be visible in both package and project. If someone know the code please share to me.

Comment: The Package Explorer probably just uses the full new wizards set defined by the `org.eclipse.ui.newWizards` extension point.

Comment: Mr.greg,Thank you very much for not only answering about eclipse wizard but also correcting my English grammar errors.